# Calculated member fees

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, evaluating-civicrm, price-sets

Currently exploring CiviCRM as a possible replacement for our current CRM. Our members are all union organisations and the membership dues are a calculation based on a fee x number of members in the affiliated organisation. This means that every member pays a different amount and we need to be able to calculate the fee for each member. From what I've seen you can set up multiple membership types and price sets but I haven't found anything for doing calculated fees. Do any of you do this or know if it's possible?

Many thanks in advance.
Chris

Answer (score 2):

If you run your CiviCRM on a Drupal instance you can use Webform CiviCRM module in combination with Webform Calculator module that you can use for that exact scenario.

Alternatively - see here for an example of how you can use conditionals to build your own fees: [How can I create early bird fees with Webform CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24578/how-can-i-create-early-bird-fees-with-webform-civicrm) - the example is for a participant (event) fee, but a membership fee can be built similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be achieved within CiviCRM using a fairly simple custom extension to do the calculation.