# How can I create early bird fees with Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: webform-civicrm, price-sets

In native CiviCRM I would do this with a priceset; how do I do this with Webform CiviCRM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a field of type Date to the webform -> set it to default: now - and set it such that start date = now and end date = now; deselect the Enable popup calendar
   [image]
2. Conditionals: example:
   [image]
3. Hide the date field with CSS and hide your element with CSS - as you can see above mine is called today:

> ```
> .webform-component--today {
>   display: none; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Very clever solution!